# forloop in palindrome

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am practising a string palindrome. Is my code in my for loop right?

```
public static void main (String args[]) 
{
    String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a String:");
    String finalword = word.replaceAll(" ","").toLowerCase();

    for (int x = word.length(); x >= word.length()-1; x--) 
    {
        finalword.charAt(x);
    }

    if(word.equals(finalword)) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Palindrome");
    }
    else 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a Palindrome");
    }
}
```

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Have you tried running the program yourself and seeing what happens?

Comment: `finalword.charAt(x);` does not do anything (apart from possibly throwing an exception). So the answer to your question is: no.

Comment: Maybe an  IndexBoundOutException :)

Comment: @vr1911428 Is it homework?

Comment: @smit it is just a prctice for beginners

Comment: @vr1911428 For practice I can give you direction,some steps to follow  not actual code snippet. Will that Okay with you?

Comment: @vr1911428 I posted the answer. Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The actual string you need to work on is finalword as its length important to you.
2. For simplicity take two temp arrays like tempStart and tempLast, both has to be same length as (finalword.length /2), Dont worry about string has even or odd number of chars.
3. use for loop with two variables as follows.

   ```
    for(int x = 0, y=finalword.length(); x<finalword.length() / 2; x++,y--){
      // check tempStart and tempLast has same chars.
      // I hope you know rule for palindrome.
    }
   ```
4. if these both arrays (tempStart and tempLast) matches then its palindrome otherwise not.

I hope this will help you. If not let me know you need any more help while doing this.

Answer (score 2):

when you initiate x the value will be the length of word. it should be

int x = word.length() -1

Answer (score 0):

int x = word.length();
Will give you the length of the array of characters ie

```
"Racecar".length();
// 7
```

Then in the array that would be array[7], but you really want 6