# Java method to identify palindromes

Tags: java, for-loop, palindrome

In an exercise, we are told that the following method identifies palindromes (words that are the same backwards and forwards), but it doesn't work.  It accepts some stings that are not palindromes and we are asked to identify where the error in the method is, and to can we correct it.  The method `clean` strips white spaces and then runs `toLowerCase`.

```
public boolean checkPalindrom(String sc){
    boolean isPalindrom = true;
    String sr = clean(sc);
    for(int i = 0; i < sr.length()/2; i++){
         isPalindrom = (sr.charAt(i)==(sr.charAt(sr.length()-1 - i)));
    }
return isPalindrom;
}
```

I cannot find any strings that are not palindromes but which are accepted by this function.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Gather working input and failing input and results. Then you'll be able to look for common patterns.

Comment: You can make use of this question asked before [Palindrome Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924424/forloop-in-palindrome/13924912#13924912)

Answer (score 3):

you never break as soon as it fails, so you're returning just the very last check.

Comment: Right, and it states as palindrom "asbbcd" as an example.

Answer (score 1):

here's the fix:

```
public boolean checkPalindrom(String sc){
    boolean isPalindrom = true;
    String sr = clean(sc);
    for(int i = 0; i < sr.length()/2 && isPalindrom; ++i){
         isPalindrom = (sr.charAt(i)==(sr.charAt(sr.length()-1 - i)));
    }
return isPalindrom;
}
```

this way , as soon as you find out it's not a palindrom , you break the loop . otherwise , if it has the same letter in the middle and near it , it will be considered a palindrom .

example:

```
adcde
```